# Uwp Display Image From Table SQL

Tags: c#, sql, wcf, uwp

I have a function On my wcf service it returns Image as Bytes 
I didnt Find any idea on how to display it in my Image Control 
How can i Convert Those Bytes to an Image And thanks !

Here is my WCF Function:

```
    public List<Data.Product> Show_P()
    {

        DataTable Table = new DataTable();
        List<Data.Product> MyProductsLIST = new List<Data.Product>();
        Table = Sp.SelectData("Show_Products", null);

        if (Table.Rows.Count > 0)
                for (int i = 0; i < Table.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    Data.Product Log = new Data.Product();

                    Log._ID = Convert.ToInt32(Table.Rows[i]["ID"]);
                    Log._Name = Table.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString();
                    Log._Price = Table.Rows[i]["Price"].ToString();
                    Log._Qte = Table.Rows[i]["Qte"].ToString();
                    Log._CAT = Convert.ToInt32(Table.Rows[i]["Cat"]);
                    Log._Vote = Convert.ToInt32(Table.Rows[i]["Vote"]);
                    Log._Image = (byte[])Table.Rows[i]["Image"];

                    MyProductsLIST.Add(Log);
                }


                return MyProductsLIST;

    }
```

And in my uwp :

```
public  static List<Products> Get_Products()
{
    MspService.Service1Client Serv = new MspService.Service1Client();
    MspService.Product[] Product = Serv.Show_PAsync().Result.Show_PResult;
    List<Products> Produc = new List<Design_TesTiNg.MenuBox.Products>();

    for (int i = 0; i < Product.Length; i++)
    {
        Products Prod = new Products();
        Prod._ID = Product[i]._ID;
        Prod._Name = Product[i]._Name;
        Prod._Price = Product[i]._Price;
        Prod._Qte = Product[i]._Qte;
        Prod._CAT = Product[i]._CAT;
        Prod._Vote = Product[i]._Vote;
        Prod._Image = Product[i]._Image;
        Prod.ms = new MemoryStream(Prod._Image);
        Convert(Prod.ms,Prod._Img);
        Produc.Add(Prod);

    }
    return Produc;
```

}

So I tried to convert it that way :

```
public static async void Convert(MemoryStream mem, BitmapImage Img)
        {
            IRandomAccessStream a1 = await ConvertToRandomAccessStream(mem);
            Img = new BitmapImage();
            await Img.SetSourceAsync(a1);
        }


      public static async Task<IRandomAccessStream> ConvertToRandomAccessStream(MemoryStream memoryStream)
        {
            var randomAccessStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
            var outputStream = randomAccessStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0);
            var dw = new DataWriter(outputStream);
            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => dw.WriteBytes(memoryStream.ToArray()));
            await task;
            await dw.StoreAsync();
            await outputStream.FlushAsync();
            return randomAccessStream;
        }
```

Comment: We really need to see some code to help you.

Comment: Here is My entire Code

Answer (score 0):

> it returns Image as Bytes I didnt Find any idea on how to display it in my Image Control

From your code `Log._Image = (byte[])Table.Rows[i]["Image"];`, I think your `Bytes` means byte array here. I think problem is you need to know how your images are converted from image to byte arrays. I assumed that your wcf is for saving data (include byte arrays of images) to table and retrieve them, your converting images to byte arrays work is still done in the UWP app, then I've tested your code, if I convert image to byte array in UWP app in this way:

```
var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/1.jpeg"));
var b64 = await ConvertStorageFileToBase64String(file);

private async Task<byte[]> ConvertStorageFileToBase64String(StorageFile File)
{
    var stream = await File.OpenReadAsync();

    using (var dataReader = new DataReader(stream))
    {
        var bytes = new byte[stream.Size];
        await dataReader.LoadAsync((uint)stream.Size);
        dataReader.ReadBytes(bytes);

        return bytes;
    }
}
```

And convert back using your method like this:

```
MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(b64);
IRandomAccessStream a1 = await ConvertToRandomAccessStream(mem);
var Img = new BitmapImage();
await Img.SetSourceAsync(a1);
myimg.Source = Img;  //myimg is the name of the image control.
```

The image can be correctly showed in image control. So if your code can't work by your side, please update your code for converting image to byte array, or maybe you can upload your sample so can we have a test.